# next.js dynamic import component from object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have an object of components that I'll looking to dynamically import using `next/dynmaic`

I'm just wondering is it possible.

This is the object in question

```
// IconComponents.tsx

import {
    Tick,
    Star
} from 'components/Icons';

export interface Map {
  [name: string]: JSX.Element;
}

const IconObject: Map = {
  tick: <Tick />,
  star: <Star />,
};

export default IconObject;
```

If I import this in a different file

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

const DynamicComponent = dynamic(() => import('./Icons/IconComponents'));
```

I get the following error

> Argument of type '() => Promise<typeof import("...path")>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DynamicOptions<{}> | Loader<{}>'.

> Type '() => Promise<typeof import("...path")>' is not assignable to type '() => LoaderComponent<{}>'.

Am I doing sometihng wrong, I need all the component in the object so should I be looping through it? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
dynamic(callback)
```

looks like `callback` provided in `dynamic` should return react components

try

```
const DynamicComponent = dynamic(() => import('./Icons/IconComponents').tick);
```

Comment: or something like this
const DynamicComponent = dynamic(async () => ({
 default: (await import('./Icons/IconComponents')).tick,
}));
```